# Enable or disable textbox on value changed in other textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form in which various textboxes are there and want to enable or disable the textbox if value entered in other textbox is greater than 0. Tried different solutions but no luck as of now. Lastly, I have tried this :

```
protected void TextBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox7.Text.Trim().Length>0)
    {
        TextBox9.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        TextBox9.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code you are testing for the length of the data in TextBox7, but in your test description you say that you want to test for a value of "0".  Is this a typo?  Or what exactly do you want to check for?

Comment: Change your code to `TextBox9.Enabled = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox7.Text);` for the same result but faster performance and better readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code looks fine except some irritating names(try to follow some naming conventions). Since it is web forms you have to make sure the following things to make it work:

- [AutoPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the corresponding control is set to true
- It will trigger only when the control loses focus

Answer (score 1):

try this. first i think you need to disable textbox 9 first to get your requirement.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox9.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text.Trim()) > 0)
            {
                textBox9.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                textBox9.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox7.Text) ? TextBox9.Enabled = true : TextBox9.Enabled = false;
```

look for it being a string.IsNullOrEmpty(...), you could replace your original code with this if you wanted but the other line should work perfectly for you too

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox7.Text))
{
    TextBox9.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
    TextBox9.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Correct would be `TextBox9.Enabled = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox7.Text);`.

Comment: @MaxPlay just because its not your way doesnt mean its wrong if it works

Comment: No, it does not work. At least not when you try to have the same result as the code that was given in the question. `textBox1.Text.Trim()) > 0` is not equal to `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` but `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`. I wouldn't correct you, if there wasn't a real reason for it.